# I need to sum all odd fibonacci numbers but only works for some numbers

Tags: javascript

Task: Given a positive integer num, return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to num.

The first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 1 and 1. Every additional number in the sequence is the sum of the two previous numbers. The first six numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and 8.

For example, sumFibs(10) should return 10 because all odd Fibonacci numbers less than 10 are 1, 1, 3, and 5.

This is on freecodecamp. I have looked at examples I know I could of easily copied them but I wanted to write my own code, can someone explain why I get these [results](http://prntscr.com/e2ve8l) and where I've gone wrong? Thanks.

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var arr = [0, 1, 1]; //array of fibonacci numbers
  var fin = 0; //variable for final number
  for(var i = 3;i < 35;i++)
    {
      arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2];
    }
  // loop to make fibonacci numbers
  for(var x = 0; x < arr.length-1; x++)
    {
        if(arr[x] <= num  && (arr[x] % 2 === 0))
          {
          fin += arr[x];
          }//if to check if array of fibonacci numbers[x] is less than num && if it is odd
    }//loop to go through every fibonacci number
  return fin;
}
sumFibs(1000);
```

Comment: Think about what `arr[x] % 2 === 0` means for a few minutes.

Comment: `for(var i = 3;i < 35;i++)` the 35 is limiting the total number of numbers to add in your second loop - just in case `num` happens to be very big.

Comment: @Villa7_ The 34th Fibonacci number is larger than the test cases.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ah right, I'm checking if its even, I did have it to !(arr[x] % 2) but that also didn't work

Comment: @molbdnilo i have just combined the two to make !(arr[x] % 2 === 0) and now it works, thanks for the tip

Comment: You could just change `=== 0` to `=== 1` or `!== 0`

Comment: You can actually solve this problem using just one loop and no array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the modulo operation:

```
    if(arr[x] <= num  && (arr[x] % 2 === 0))
```

You are asking two things:

1. if the arr[x] value is less than the number (check)
2. if the arr[x] value is even, NOT odd.

That is where your issue is occurring.

Rather you should use:

```
    if(arr[x] <= num  && (arr[x] % 2 != 0))
```

Comment: Also, I didn't touch on the other comments above. You are only building your fibonacci array to 35 elements. You could consider building the array list as you go perhaps through recursion to work with any number (though it is not necessary as defined in your test cases)?

Comment: sounds rather advanced D: but yes this is correct however I did !(arr[x] % 2 === 0) and it seems to work.

Comment: everything in programming seems advanced when you first learn it :) or at least for me. (aside from the simple notions). You're on the right path, modulo operations can be tricky at first, but when in doubt try logging everything and seeing how things work. I'm not a JS expert but both solutions should be the same, just different syntax. Try this link here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp, probably elucidate a few things

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution :

```
function sumFibs(num) 
{
    var prev=0,curr=1,result=0,added;
     while(curr<=num)
     {
         if(curr % 2 !=0)
         {
         result+=curr;
         }
         added= curr+prev;
         prev=curr;
         curr=added;
     }
    return result;
}
sumFibs(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  var firstNum = 0;
  var secondNum = 1;
  var sequence = [];
  var index = [];
  while (firstNum <= num) {
    sequence.push(firstNum, secondNum);
    firstNum = firstNum + secondNum;
    secondNum = firstNum + secondNum;
    /**/

    }
  for (var key in sequence) {
  if (sequence[key] <= num) {
    index.push(sequence[key]);
  }}  
  //return index;
  var oddIndex = [];
  for (var key in index) {
    if (index[key] % 2 !== 0) {
      oddIndex.push(index[key]);
    }
  }
  // return oddIndex;
  var output = oddIndex.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
  });
  return output;
}

sumFibs(75025); //should return 135721
```